# What happens to uncommited messages if the application suddenly fails?

Tags: ibm-mq

[IBM MQ documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=multiplatforms-local-units-work) says:

"If an application disconnects (MQDISC) from a queue manager while a global unit of work coordinated by IBM® MQ is still active, an attempt is made to commit the unit of work. If, however, the application terminates without disconnecting, the unit of work is rolled back as the application is deemed to have terminated abnormally."

The case of application issuing a MQDISC is clear. My doubt is about the second scenario: let's say I'm putting messages and the applicative servers suddenly loss power before the commit. How does the rollback work if the application is not available at all? Would those message end in the DLQ, or...?

Comment: On an uncommitted PUT the message will be gone.   On an uncommitted GET the message will be rolled back to the queue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JoshMc you are right and it makes sense: the application shouldn't believe the messages were sent if the transaction never finished.

PS: for some reason, I can't accept your answer as the good one :(